# Automapper Member AddTransform doesn't work when using types instead of generics

Tags: c#, automapper

This works fine

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Test, opt => opt.AddTransform(x => "test"))
        );
```

But this always returns a null

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Source), typeof(Dest))
                .ForMember("Test", opt => opt.AddTransform(x => "test"))
        );
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have a need to use the AddTransform but I've only got access to the property name of the destination and not Expression<Func<Dest, object>> so I can't use the generic property. It's weird how it works for one but not the other

Comment: No, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3387